# Implement this java-script in joomla 3 (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I found this great piece of code here on stackoverflow and this could be my long searched solution but I can`t get it to run on my joomla 3.

Java-Script:

```
$('#showVideo').click(function() {
$('#video').show().html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/48459576?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');
$('#showVideo').hide().html;})
```

See on http://jsfiddle.net/1tszLnhx/2/

After loading the script in the header after all the jquery I get the following error when I click on the actual "Click to start Video"-Link:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)`

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody can help me out with this?

Comment: It's hard to say from what you've provided however try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in the above snippet and run it again.

Comment: Thanks Ilias, I will try as soon as possible - what information do you need? I will provide whatever is necessary to get this issue solved!Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @ Ilias:  I have tried it now: The result is that I get no error anymore, but there is also nothing happening.

Comment: @ Ilias: Now I have found another solution, but same result when I try to build it in my joomla 3 portal. Here is the solution and it is quite exacly what I was searching for https://jsfiddle.net/8dyom878/

Comment: @Jacob Where are you putting this code? In the template file's head section and if yes is it inside a `jQuery( document ).ready(function() { //the above snippet here});` [learn more](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) ? Run it again and tell us.

Comment: @ Ilias: I have tried it - still no result - I also updated the jsfiddle to a newer version maybe there is somewhere the catch. http://jsfiddle.net/8dyom878/4/

Comment: @ Ilias: so it is now basically working, but when I klick on the image the content of the loading IFrame is an error page of mine (Error 404). It redirects to following site "http://www.example.com/undefined", where it should load the Iframe.

Comment: Does your image have an `id` ? Put an id to it and change this part of the jsfiddle: `jQuery('img').attr('data-video')` to this `jQuery('#yourimageid').attr('data-video')` and run it again. Generally in your actual implementation of the fiddle code in your website try to be more specific regarding the elements' selectors e.g. classnames and ids.

Comment: @ilias: You are my personal hero!! Everything is working like a charm now - thanks a lot - I`ll post this solution to the vimeo community so more people can use it! (Last Version http://jsfiddle.net/8dyom878/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in the above snippet.
Generally in your actual implementation of the fiddle code in your website try to be more specific regarding the elements' selectors e.g. classnames and ids.

Wrap it around a 
`jQuery( document ).ready(function() { //the above snippet here});`

and change the part
 
`jQuery('img').attr('data-video')` 

to this 
`jQuery('#yourimageid').attr('data-video')`